# cawler: html file encodings issue

Tags: character-encoding, web-crawler

I try to write a crawler to get some information.But I find the word is different in webpage source.For example, the word **Möller** is **M&#246;ller** in html file.
I want to know how can I recover it after I get the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Having fix this problem and provide the answer in case some beginner meet the same problem.
I use chr() to substitute the wrong code, for example use chr(246) to substitute &#246;
If there is better solution, please tell me.